# What is wrong with my select for update skip locked oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I need to update multiple records in a table by matching a particular column (dest_file_path in this case). I'm joining the table with itself. Inner select to get the matching column joined with the same table to get all the records with the one matching column

```
update job_queue 
set status = 'RUNNING', last_updated_time = systimestamp 
where rowid in
(
select jq.rowid from job_queue jq,
(select DEST_FILE_PATH from JOB_QUEUE 
where status not in ('RUNNING','FINISHED','SKIPPED') and operation_type in ('copy') 
order by case when status='FAILED' then 0 else 1 end desc, dest_file_path fetch first 1 rows only) dest
where jq.dest_file_path = dest.dest_file_path and jq.operation_type='copy'
)
for update skip locked;
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
Error at Command Line : 25 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Although if I do a simple select instead of update it works just fine. Here is the select query.

```
select rowid,dest_file_path from job_queue
where rowid in
(
select jq.rowid from job_queue jq,
(select DEST_FILE_PATH from JOB_QUEUE 
where dest_file_path='/file/path' 
and status not in ('RUNNING','FINISHED','SKIPPED') and operation_type in ('copy') 
order by case when status='FAILED' then 0 else 1 end desc, dest_file_path fetch first 1 rows only) dest
where jq.dest_file_path = dest.dest_file_path and jq.operation_type='copy'
)
for update skip locked;
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle the update.

Answer (score 0):

The `for update` clause only exists for `select` statements, not for `update` statements (which have to lock the rows they update).  It sounds like you want to run the `select for update` first, load the key(s) into a local variable/ collection, then do a subsequent `update` using the values you saved off.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You are correct I'm trying to update subsequently with the for update. Do you have any suggestion so as to how I can solve this with a single query?

Comment: @KireetBhat - Why does it have to be a single query?  What is the downside to a simple two-step operation?

Comment: There is no downside, just that I was doing the same in a postgres before with a single query so I assumed that it could be done the same way in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

you can run your query using pl/sql.

```
BEGIN
   FOR R
      IN (SELECT JQ.ROWID
            FROM JOB_QUEUE JQ,
                 (SELECT *
                    FROM (  SELECT DEST_FILE_PATH
                              FROM JOB_QUEUE
                             WHERE     STATUS NOT IN ('RUNNING',
                                                      'FINISHED',
                                                      'SKIPPED')
                                   AND OPERATION_TYPE IN ('copy')
                          ORDER BY (CASE STATUS
                                       WHEN 'FAILED' THEN 0
                                       ELSE 1
                                    END) DESC)
                   WHERE ROWNUM = 1) DEST
           WHERE     JQ.DEST_FILE_PATH = DEST.DEST_FILE_PATH
                 AND JQ.OPERATION_TYPE = 'copy'
          FOR UPDATE
             SKIP LOCKED)
   LOOP
      UPDATE JOB_QUEUE
         SET STATUS = 'RUNNING', LAST_UPDATED_TIME = SYSTIMESTAMP
       WHERE ROWID = R.ROWID;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm getting this error after running your query.                                 
Error at Command Line : 52 Column : 18
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @KireetBhat, The FOR UPDATE clause is only valid for the top-level SQL statement, not for subqueries and FETCH feature is not available in 11g, It was introduced in 12c. 
you can run your query using pl/sql. I am updating my answer above as pl/sql query.